# Audio player only plays, doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to make a simple audio player but it's just not working fine!

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay(element) {

  element.classList.toggle("playing");

  if (isPlaying) {
    document.getElementById("audio").pause();
    document.getElementById("audio").currentTime = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
  }

}

document.getElementById("audio").onplaying = function() {
  var isPlaying = true;
};

document.getElementById("audio").onpause = function() {
  var isPlaying = false;
};
```

**Please help me!**

Answer (score 0):

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
// use .paused instead
// var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay(element) {
  var promise;

  if (!audio.paused) { /* isPlaying */
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    element.classList.remove("playing");
  } else {
    // play is not instant, it returns a promise
    promise = audio.play();
    if (promise.then !== undefined) {
        promise.then(function () {
            element.classList.add("playing");
        });
    } else { /* old API */
        element.classList.add("playing");
    }

  }

}

audio.onplaying = function() {
  ;
};

audio.onpause = function() {
  ;
};
```

Make sure to put the `<script>` at the end of the `<body>`

```
        <script>/* put script at the end of body */</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure the audio source for `<audio>` is an actual audio file. (not an html file containing audio) Open console and look at network requests.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paused' of null
    at togglePlay ((index):19)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick ((index):91)` // What Chrome says

Comment: fix this line first, I can't see your HTML `var audio = document.getElementById("audio");` make sure to have <audio id="audio" ...

Comment: Everything's fine but it doesn't work! Check [my website](https://bernardovs23.neocities.org/)'s source code

Comment: see my edit, https://nofile.io/g/KU1i8L4jxhIykUaCLYmMsbaJ8WJdKvu4MTMejAz4jy76bShLglzbrgcggSzbXRMB/Software+Upgrade.mp3/ is not an audio file